# Android Bluetooth Application crashed on start

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm relatively new to coding on Android Studio using Java. The project I'm working on is a simple bluetooth application that is supposed to control motors on a device. Every time I launch it on the emulator it crashes.

In logcat these are the errors that appear:

2020-11-14 19:04:57.496 1598-1816/com.android.bluetooth E/bt_btm: BTM_BleObserve Observe not active

2020-11-14 19:45:03.330 518-1637/system_process E/WifiThreadRunner: WifiThreadRunner.call() timed out!
java.lang.Throwable: Stack trace:
at com.android.server.wifi.WifiThreadRunner.call(WifiThreadRunner.java:80)
at com.android.server.wifi.WifiServiceImpl.getScanResults(WifiServiceImpl.java:2725)
at android.net.wifi.IWifiManager$Stub.onTransact(IWifiManager.java:730)
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1159)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)
2020-11-14 19:50:56.728 518-541/system_process E/JobScheduler.Background: App com.google.android.gms became active but still in NEVER bucket

I understand the emulator cannot replicate another device, however I don't understand why it crashes at the start. Is there a problem with the Bluetooth Client code or perhaps is there a problem with the layout?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

emulator does not have bluetooth. It wil crash.Always use real device to test Bluetooth related code.

```
  val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()/*wil 
  produce null for emulator and hence most likely creating crash.Cant't tell exactly  
  which place and  where its crashing because you have not posted any code.*/
```